# Swift iOS - How to line up a sublayer position to match the center of button text

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, centering

I have a button that is text. I added a red background subLayer and I made the backgroundLayer's width and height bigger then the button text. I tried to center the background layer to the button using:

```
backgroundLayer.position = button.center
```

It's not centering. This is what I get:

[image]

I know I can set the background color and cornerRadius on the button directly but when I do it that way the red background hugs the text:

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

[image]

I want the redbackground to be wider and taller then the text:

```
backgroundLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonTextSize.width + 10, height: buttonTextSize.height + 5
```

I would Photoshop an example but I don't have Photshop in front of me at the moment. This is the closest I can find. This is a button from Vimeo. They aren't using text but the backgroundLayer is much wider and taller then the button image and the backgroundLayer's position is aligned with the button's midX and midY:

[image]

**How do I get the position of the background subLayer to line up with the center of the button's text?**

```
let button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23)
    return button
}()

let backgroundLayer: CALayer = {
    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.cornerRadius = 10
    return layer
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    view.addSubview(button)
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    let buttonText = button.titleLabel?.text
    let buttonTextSize = (buttonText! as NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23.0)])

    // I added 10 points to the backgroundLayer's width and 5 points to the backgroundLayer's height so its wider then the text
    backgroundLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonTextSize.width + 10, height: buttonTextSize.height + 5)
    button.layer.insertSublayer(backgroundLayer, at: 0)

    backgroundLayer.position = button.center
}
```

Comment: use backgroundLayer.frame = button.bounds

Comment: the backgroundLayer is wider and taller then the text: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonTextSize.width + 10, height: buttonTextSize.height + 5)

Comment: @ReinierMelian thanks for the help. I tried backgroundLayer.frame = button.bounds but it didn't work.

Comment: @matt I know how to do it the regular way, I can just use button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red. ,button.layer.cornerRadius = 10. I'm just getting into CALayers (never used them in depth before) and I wanted to know why the CALayer's position wouldn't align with the button's center

Comment: @matt yes, but the catch is the subLayer is wider and taller then the text of the button. Btw I just tried: backgroundLayer.position = CGPoint(x: button.bounds.midX, y: button.bounds.midY) but I still couldn't get it. And thanks for the clarification about: "The button's center is not its bounds center; it's its frame center."

Comment: @matt thanks for the help. I just updated the answer. I hope is a bit more clearer. I added some pictures too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172020/discussion-between-lance-samaria-and-matt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a button that seems to look the way you want (of course you can adjust any parameters that don't suit your sensibilities):

[image]

This button is automatically red, corner-rounded, and considerably larger than its text (even when the button is *positioned* using auto layout).

Here's how it was achieved through a subclass:

```
class MyRedButton : UIButton {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.backgroundColor = .red
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var sz = super.intrinsicContentSize
        sz.width += 30; sz.height += 30
        return sz
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Matt's upvoted answer is correct.

Two things he pointed out to me in the comments that I was initially doing wrong was.

1. I tried to set `backgroundLayer.position = button.center`. This is wrong because the button's center is based on the frame's *center* and not it's *bounds* center. I should've set the backgroundLayer.position to match the center of the button's bounds
2. I tried to set the backgroundLayer's position to the button's center in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` which he said the button's bounds weren't known yet so the backgroundLayer had no information to base it on. I was supposed to add the code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Here's the code here:

```
// 1. add the code to viewDidLayoutSubviews
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let text = button.titleLabel?.text
    let textSize = (text! as NSString).size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23.0)])

    backgroundLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textSize.width + 10, height: textSize.height + 5)
    button.layer.insertSublayer(backgroundLayer, at: 0)

    // 2. get the buttons bound's center by accessing it's midX and midY
    let buttonMidX = button.bounds.midX
    let buttonMidY = button.bounds.midY
    let buttonBoundsCenter = CGPoint(x: buttonMidX, y: buttonMidY)

    // 3. set the backgroundLayer's postion to the buttonBoundsCenter
    backgroundLayer.position = buttonBoundsCenter
}
```

And it works:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice 